# What is order of complexity here?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity, complexity-theory

```
   for(int i = n; i > 0; i/=3){
       for(int j = 0; j < i; j++){
           System.out.println("Hello");
       }
   }
```

Is it `O(n)` or `O(nlog n)`?

The outer loop will run log<sub>3</sub> n times - as the iterator is getting factored by a constant of 3.

Thus, the outer loop will be called **log<sub>3</sub> n** times

belongs to `O(nlog n)`?

Answer (score 2):

This part `n + n/3 + n/9 + ..... = n/3 (1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + ....)` is not correct.

Actually

`n + n/3 + n/9 + .....`  =  `n( 1 + 1/3 + 1/9 +...)`

and `1 + 1/3 + 1/9 + ...`  = [**a / (1-r)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula) where `a = 1` and `r = 1/3`

which converges to `3/2`.

Therefore the complexity is `O(n*(3/2))` or `O(n)`

Actually intuitively I would think like this: lets assume outer loop gives you a size of the input for a problem that you want to solve for. 
So the inner loop is like writing multiple for loops of varying sizes like below:

```
for ( k = 1 to n )

for ( k = 1 to n/3 )

for ( k = 1 to n/9 )

....
```

If you look at these for loops the complexity seems to converge to `O(n)` because the number of for loops depends on `n` and is *diminishing*, but if it were some constant like `k` then it would be `O(n*k)`